# Ethernet down after Server restart

Tags: windows-server-2016, hp-proliant

we have a HPE Server Gen10 in usage as backupserver,

recently server was restarted and lost connectivity afterwards.But server is running without having connectivity. Even Monitoring system  displaying server is down.

So I get myself a screen and keyboard to have a look on the server ->
I only recognized the "ethernet symbol" in left bottom corner had this yellow sign, after logon however the system had Ethernet connection i even could logon with a domain "adminuser".

The server is running a windows server 2016 OS and has Nic teaming

Comment: did you check configurations of ethernet cards

Comment: Could be a  DHCP no longer providing the correct IP.

Comment: I did have a look on it after the logon and the "Nic Teaming card" has a proper IP which is static therefore, it can't be a DHCP error as it is static and the DNS is set properly